# Translate a hook from Biggie`s Respect

Tags: lyrics

Please translate a text below in English:

```
Me holla respect, to all the gun men dem
Gun men alone, keep gun men friend
Fire bun, fi all the informer dem
Informer lone keep informer friend
```

The song you can find on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xq8mGJc5xQE)

Comment: http://genius.com/The-notorious-big-respect-lyrics

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like :
Respect to the gangsters (gunmen) - a gangster is another gangster's friend.

there's a fire burning ("Fire bun") for all the informers :
an informer's only friend is him/herself.

Comment: what does it mean "dem" in the case?

Comment: @kharandziuk the word "dem" is just a the way the pronoun *them* is pronounced in a Jamaican accent - however, when used after a noun it makes it plural (there's >1 gun man, >1 informer).